# Can I export an project with the command line to a XPO file? (AX 2009)

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, x++, axapta, ax

Is it possible to export an project with the command line to a XPO file? (AX 2009)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the classes C\SysStartupCmd*.  I know there are some funky command line tools you can use, but the easiest thing I would think is to create your own class that "does" what you want, than extend the SysStartupCmd class.

A VERY good example is Classes\SysStartupCmdCompileAll.  You only need one method, and it accepts a parameter, and you add your case in the C\SysStartupCmd\construct method.

Then to call it, you call the client from the command line like, "ax32.exe -startupcmd=compileall_+" where the "+" is your parameter, if you choose to have one.  "compileall" is what is referenced in the construct of the SysStartupCmd, and then you create your class with one method to do what you would like.

Comment: The SysStartupCmdAOTImport class does the reverse. You will have to specify both a project and a file (or use a naming convention and a predefined folder).

Comment: Jan> Your class might point him a bit more in the right direction :).  I couldn't remember what was already available and going off of memory and google.